# Is it possible to use a device to run one application exclusively?

Tags: android

I have developed an app which is destined for tablets in hospitals for patients use.

Right now I am being asked to make the tablet's only functionality be my app to prevent personel or any person from using it for web browsing, gaming or anything else.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are products on the market that offer 'kiosk mode' style device lock down whereby you can restrict applications.

[Surelock](http://www.42gears.com/surelock/surelockandroid.html)

[SuperLockLite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superkiosk.ospolice.superlocklite)

Also see this Stackoverflow post for similar discussion.

[Kiosk mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android)

Comment: thanks Sharpedges! surelock is perfect. My only problem now is that I haven´t been able to find out what are the limitations the trial version comes with. Is it just less features or will it stop working after some days?

Comment: Very good question, I am afraid I didn't know the answer! I e-mailed Surelock support and got the following reply:

Here are the limitation of SureLock Android Free version:

 

1.       Free version allows maximum of 2 applications only.

2.       Free version displays reminder messages periodically

3.       Some wallpaper display settings are not available in free version

Hope this helps :)

Comment: haha Did the same thing, got the same response :) thanks!

Comment: I would really like to know how Surelock is able to hide Home and back button to do it within my app. Can you please help me to achive this?

Comment: I believe you need to have the device rooted and running Honeycomb+ in order to use the setting 'Hide bottom bar' using Surelock.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best solution to kiosk mode I've found so far
http://thebitplague.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/kiosk-mode-on-the-nexus-7/

Answer (score 1):

android is a linux OS and you can create users with specific permission,

i never did this but I've seen it: http://l4android.org/

I hope might help

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom android version, in order to prevent users to use the back button or to acceas settings, for instance. You have to take care of restarting your app if it crashes. You can ovverride the home launcher in order to be your app the only launchable. You want to take same sort of "back door" just in case you want to grant super user access